# An algorithm determining whether two subgroups of a finitely generated free group are automorphic

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

In the book Lyndon, Schupp, Combinatorial Group Theory, P.30 in the edition from 2000 They mention an unpublished work by Waldhausen that is said to give an algorithm to determine whether two subgroups are automorphic given their free generators. I searched for papers written by Waldhausen But I didn't find it. Has Waldhausen or anyone else published a solution to this problem? Where can i find it? This is a copy of a post from [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677657/an-algorithm-determining-whether-two-subgroups-of-a-free-group-are-automorphic)

Comment: "give an algorithm to determine whether two subgroups are automorphic given their free generators" is somewhat unclear. Fortunately I have Lyndon-Schupp with me. The general question is: given two $n$-tuples $u$ and $v$ in a f.g. free group $F$ (possibly not free or generating), determine if there exists an automorphism of $F$ mapping $u$ to $v$. Typically this is interesting when $u,v$ are free (and not generating, since this is trivial then). They also mention the question whether there's an automorphism of $F$ mapping $\langle u\rangle$ to $\langle v\rangle$.

Comment: Second given that you were asked clarification on MathSE about your nonstandard use of "automorphic", you should have made an effort to clarify it before reposting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a comment on the math.SE link, the OP wants to understand the question of deciding when two (finitely generated) subgroups of a given free group $F$ are equivalent by an automorphism of $F$.

I believe that this was first solved by Gersten:

> S. Gersten, On Whitehead’s algorithm, Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 10 (1984) 281–
>   284.
>
> Abstract. One can decide effectively when two finitely generated subgroups of a finitely generated free group $F$ are equivalent under an automorphism of $F$. The subgroup of automorphisms of $F$ mapping a given finitely generated subgroup $S$ of $F$ into a conjugate of $S$ is finitely
>   presented.

Gersten states that the question asked by the OP was first raised by Whitehead. He also states that he settles this question of Whitehead, and does not cite any papers of Waldhausen. So I guess the paper of Waldhausen never appeared...

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: OP= Original Poster means the person who posted the question: you! https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420

Comment: There is something weird about the time line. This paper is from 1984 and it is not mentioned in Lyndon & Schupp Which is from 2000.

Comment: @NoamKolodner the 2000 book is just a reprint from the 1977 edition. By the way, Lyndon died in 1988.

Comment: @NoamKolodner Lyndon and Schupp has not been updated since its original publication.

Comment: (...and contains many, many errors...)

Comment: Isn't this just an announcement? Is there a full proof somewhere?